# Understanding cpu shares in cloud foundry

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, containers, cloud-foundry, cgroups

According to this [documentation](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/container-security.html#cpu), CPU shares is calculated as

```
process_cpu.shares = min( 1024*(application_memory / 8 GB), 1024)
```

According to this formula, if an application is assigned 1GB memory, then it should get 128 CPU shares. `1024*(1/8)`. However, if we SSH into the application and check the `cpu.shares` we get 122

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpu.shares
122
```

Here are the observations:

| Memory | Calculated `cpu.share` | Observed `cpu.share` | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1GB | 128 | 122 | ~5% difference |
| 1.5GB/1536MB | 192 | 184 | ~5% difference |
| 2GB | 256 | 256 |  |
| 3GB | 384 | 384 |  |
| 4GB | 512 | 512 |  |
| 5GB | 640 | 634 | ~1% difference |
| 5.5GB/5632MB | 704 | 696 | ~2% difference |
| 8GB | 1024 | 1024 |  |

Why is it that for some values there is this discrepancy (Such as 1G,1.5G,5G etc..) while others (like 2,3,4 - 6,7,8) are consistent with the calculation. I believe that I am missing something from Cgroups perspective for this calculation.  Is this specific to CF or is it something to do with the way Linux calculates resource allocation in Cgroups in general? Is there a headroom always reserved?

Comment: I'm not sure where the 8G is coming from in the docs. That seems arbitrary. I thought it was in relation to the available memory on your Cell. I could be wrong though.

Comment: 8GB is fine..But my real question is why the CPU share assigned is lower than the calculated value

Comment: What I'm getting at is if it's based on your Cell size, not the arbitrary value 8G, then the calculations will differ. It's also possible that it's based on the RAM allocated to Diego for running apps and not the total RAM on your Cells, which would further skew the numbers. Anyway, to me the docs seem a little sketchy, it's probably best to dig up the code and look at what it's doing.